# How can I make SignerSignEx2 use the machine key store instead of the user one?

Tags: c#, signing, authenticode

I'm currently trying to use the [SignerSignEx2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968155(v=vs.85).aspx) function to sign a DLL with Authenticode. For that purpose I created a private key and put it into the machine key store (so the file would be stored in *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys*).

Unfortunately it seems that the SignerSignEx2 function only looks for keys in the user store (when I put the keys into the user store (so that the file is stored in *C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA{user-id}*) it works fine).

Does anyone know of a way to call SignerSignEx2 in such a way that it uses the machine key store instead of the user store?

Essentially the functionality should be similar to the [CspParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which allows using CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore to control which key store is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE flag when opening Certificate Store to get what you need.